# Pagination in html table (Client Side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, client-side

Need easy and light paging in HTML table using jquery. I have use webservice to fill the table with the help of JSON. Now I need to add paging. Thanks in advance. Structure of my HTML table

```
<tr>
    <th> Id </th>
  <th> Code </th>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Gender </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.trirand.com/blog/ jqGrid is very popular and should help

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below url for sorting html.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/